# How to produce a consolidated source file?

Tags: matlab

Does MATLAB have the following capability: take source code that directly includes other `.m` files and output the source that would result from merging all included files?

For example, consider `script_one.m`:

```
% some matlab code
script_two
% more matlab code
```

I would like to programmatically generate the `.m` file that would result from copying and pasting the contents of `script_two.m` into `script_one.m`. This is difficult to do with normal scripting tools because I would essentially need a MATLAB symbol table to determine which identifiers correspond to sourceable scripts. I highly doubt that Matlab provides such a facility, but am open to other ideas.

The "use case" is the need to modify the source (using `sed`) but the changes need to propagated to any dependent scripts, such as `script_two.m`. As I don't have a listing of the dependent scripts, they can only be identified by going through the source manually (and it needs to be done on a large number of dynamically created files).

Some details on the use case:
The main script (script_one) is called with dynamically created header files, e.g., `matlab [args] -r 'some definitions; script_two; script_three; others; main_script();quit()'`. This is run on machine A; for load balancing, it may need to be run instead on machines B, C, etc, which mount the file system of A at some point. Any paths in the included `.m` files (which are mainly used as headers) would need to be essentially chrooted to work on the new host. The simplest solution would be to preprocess the code which was generated for machine A, using `sed` to replace all paths for the new host (B, C, etc.). It can of course be solved by making the changes in matlab, but a sed one-liner is a more attractive solution in terms of parsimony.

Comment: and the change in output can't be accomplished via functions and inputs to them? I'm doubting your solution is the "right" one for the use case...Can you provide more details on it?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: Yes, they could definitely be accomplished using arguments to functions, but I was seeking a way to avoid having to rewrite things, if I could make all the changes using `sed`. I'll update my question with details of the particular use case.

Comment: Well, your solutions seems a lot more complicated than rewriting in MATLAB...but that depends on your familiarity with each tool, I guess. In any case, this will inevitably result in the use of an `eval()`, which is almost always a sign that things can be done more efficiently and reusably...such as in this case, presumably.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no, it's not possible in MATLAB. What you want is a language feature common to languages that require compilation step before execution, but this is not MATLAB's language model, and therefore, it is only doable via hacky wacky language abuse.

You could, conceivably, create a master script, which takes care of coordinating the generation of new source files, and executing them via `eval()`:

```
[o,e] = system('<your sed command here, to generate script_one.m>');

% ... some more code

% execute newly generated M-file
[outputs] = eval('script_one');
```

But I hope you see and agree that this turns into spaghetti *really* quickly.

Executing a script with changing contexts and parameters is exactly what the [function](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html) language feature was invented for :)

Comment: Thanks, I expected an answer like this, but wanted to be sure before investing too much time in rewriting.